# How do Rails ActiveRecord relationship helpers allow methods such as `user.groups.new`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails, I have created a Model that retrieves users from an LDAP database rather than from ActiveRecord. Now I am attempting to integrate my ActiveRecord models with the LDAP-based models, so I am writing methods in my models that emulate some common ActiveRecord methods.

One of the methods I am trying to emulate is one that is normally created by the has_many through relationship on ActiveRecord. In ActiveRecord, this relationship would allow the following:

```
user = User.first
groups = user.groups # == Array of Groups
groups << Group.create(name: "Test") # How does Rails allow this?
```

How exactly does Rails allow this? I've tried dynamically assigning methods to the array instance returned by user.groups, but there doesn't seem to be any way to make those methods aware of which user record the array was created from. (So they can assign `user_id` on the new relationship record.) What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though `user.groups` appears to be an array of groups, it's actually an entirely separate class -- a Rails internal class that you usually don't know much about called an association proxy. The proxy responds to methods like `<<`, `create`, `new` and so on by proxying requests to the target class and then setting the association appropriately.

If you want similar functionality you'll have to implement your own kind of proxy associations. Doing so will be pretty complicated, but this might get you started.

```
module LDAP
  class Association
    attr_accessor :source, :target

    def initialize(source, target)
      @source = source
      @target = target
    end

    def <<(obj)
      @source.group_ids = [group_ids + obj].flatten.uniq
      @source.save
    end

  end
end

class User
  def groups
    LDAP::Association.new(self, Group)
  end
end
```

This is not even particularly close to how ActiveRecord implements association proxies. However, this is quite a bit simpler than ActiveRecord's solution and should be enough to duplicate some basic ActiveRecord functionality.

Comment: Great! That's just was I was looking for. Strangely enough though, calling `user.groups.class` in ActiveRecord returns `Array` (and not some other class). Any idea why that is?

Comment: Rails is performing some trickery here to make this happen. It's summarized in the [Association Proxy documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy), but essentially it calls itself an Array even though what's actually being returned is an AssociationProxy instance (like `ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation`). The mechanics to achieve this, again, are complicated, and it appears to be mostly so that `is_a?(Array)` will respond with `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about doing this by peeking into the Rails Source Code, e.g. the code for the 
Group.create example above can be found in

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html

```
  def create(attributes = nil, options = {}, &block)
    if attributes.is_a?(Array)
      attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, options, &block) }
    else
      object = new(attributes, options, &block)
      object.save
      object
    end
  end
end
```